# Pebble JS Menu Items Disappear

Tags: pebble-watch, cloudpebble, pebble-js

Hi I started creating a pebble app using Pebble.JS.  I installed the app on my Pebble and I notice that some of the menu items disappear and reappear on their own.

Nothing too fancy about the code:

```html
    for(var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      var rest = data.Result.results[i];
      var showName = rest.shows[0].showName;
      items.push({
        ourid:rest.ourID,
        distance:rest.fmtDistance,
        knownfor:rest.knownForNoHTML,
        title:rest.name,    
        subtitle:showName
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're seeing is Pebble's handling of menus. From my experience, Pebble.js only displays a few menu items (up to 5 or so?), and will load the other menu items as the user scrolls down to them.

As long as those items reappear, I'm not sure there's much to be improved.

Comment: So pebble.js is significantly slower than using the C library?

Comment: @gunygoogoo One disadvantage of using Pebble.js vs C is that the JavaScript is ran on the phone, not the Pebble. Each screen change or data request needs to go through the phone to be displayed, resulting in more round trips and a slower experience. Speculating here, but that's most likely why only a few menu items are shown at a time. C's generally recommended for improved speed.